# Two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in repeated measure

Tags: repeated-measures, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

in the within-subject study design, I am comparing the two measures instrument (questionnaires) that are supposed to measure the same thing. Each gives us a single variable each (let's call it x1 and x2) and conceptually x1 should be the same as x2.

I have the resulting x1 and x2 for every participant.
x1 has a correlation of 0.7 with x2, reliable with retests.

T-test gives me a significant difference between x1 and x2 scores whereas Kolmogorov-Smirnov test gives me an insignificant difference between x1 and x2.

Can I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test for repeated measure analysis? 
Can I report Kolmogorov-Smirnov test results and claim further that it is very likely that x1 is validly measuring x2 as well?
F-score for x2 of x1 is 0.8.

I could not find any resources on this. Thank you